# Database- Sql stamtent

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i have problem in database in  my project :
i want to get column "title" from "node" table, the second table "txn" and ther is no relation between tables. the new relation is "vid" from "node" when = the "tid" from "txn" get the title
the condition is i want to get the "title" when the "vid" = "tid

this the existing Join
can i make a JOIN between "node" and "txn" ??
or can i make JOIN between 3 tables?

```
            $query = "SELECT userpoints_txn.description,  userpoints_txn.points, userpoints_txn.operation, userpoints_txn.time_stamp, users.name, users.uid, fb_user.uid, fb_user.fbu FROM userpoints_txn 
            JOIN users ON users.uid = userpoints_txn.uid

            JOIN fb_user ON users.uid = fb_user.uid
            WHERE `entity_id` = ".$nid." ORDER BY userpoints_txn.time_stamp DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can left join the three table   like this :

```
SELECT   userpoints_txn.description,    userpoints_txn.points,    userpoints_txn.operation,       userpoints_txn.time_stamp,  users.name,   users.uid,   fb_user.uid,   fb_user.fbu 
FROM   userpoints_txn 
 JOIN   users   ON   users.uid = userpoints_txn.uid
    JOIN   fb_user ON   users.uid = fb_user.uid
   JOIN   node ON node.vid=userpoints_txn.tid
  WHERE  userpoints_txn.entity_id= '".$nid."' ORDER BY userpoints_txn.time_stamp DESC
```